# Orbeon: creating a wizard form using form builder

Tags: orbeon

creating a wizard form . I had three sections 1)personal 2)family 3) test

In first two sections it should show next button and in final section test there should be a submit button where it will rediredt to jsp

can help us how to to this task .

Here is my code

```
< fr:buttons>
     <fr:button>
         <xforms:label>
               <xhtml:img width="16" height="16" src="/apps/fr/style/images/pixelmixer/right_16.png"
                                       alt=""/>
                <xhtml:span>Next</xhtml:span>
           </xforms:label>
            <xforms:setvalue ev:event="DOMActivate" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/internal/part"
             value="if (. = 'personal') then  'family' 
              else if (. = 'family') then 'test' else ''"/>
     </fr:button>
      </fr:buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a lot of work to do this correctly by hand. Since Orbeon Forms 4.0 [supports this out of the box](http://blog.orbeon.com/2012/12/form-runner-wizard-view.html), I strongly recommend you use that and provide feedback if it is missing features you need. A [Beta release](http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/01/orbeon-forms-40-beta.html) of 4.0 is available.